# Speed of updating database fields SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, query-optimization

General question on speed:

I have a section of my site where users can update account information. Considering run-time, I was wondering which of the following two approaches would be quicker.

1. Do a select query on the users existing information, compare it against what the user has submitted in the update form, and only if the field values differ, then updating the fields.

OR

1. Just overwrite the values in the SQL field, regardless of whether the data in the field matches what has been entered into the form. (This saves me one SQL SELECT request).

Also, just as an aside, does SQL respond differently if attempting to replace data with an exact copy? Is there already some built in method for not replacing what is already there?

Thanks

Comment: For the perspective of a client program, Database speed is initially about how many interactions you have with the DBMS.  So minimize that first.

Comment: Assuming that the data in a profile isn't going to be much and users are not going wild updating them, there's probably no significant difference between those two. You don't need a separate SELECT though, you could do something like: UPDATE USERPROF SET X=? etc WHERE ID=? and X<>?